# Regex Only allow characters and underscore in a token

Tags: regex

I want to test a token in which I only want to allow character and underscore. For example:

{Token-MustNotContain_AlphaCharacters0}

In this example, token must not contain a hypen and 0. Underscore is accepted.

How can I do it. So far I have:

```
^\{(.*?)(?:[a-zA-Z_])\}$
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `^\{[a-zA-Z_]*\}$`? Maybe you intended to put a quantifier on the `[a-z…]` instead of adding a new `.*?`?

Comment: ah you are right. thanks

Comment: Did you mean a letter? A character is any printed symbol. If you need to support Unicode letters you neeneed something like `\p{L}` rather than `A-Za-z`.